# how do i group by continent in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

so what i want to do is group each set of countries by continent
using array

```js
var countries = {
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "AX": "Åland Islands"
    "AL": "Albania",
    "DZ": "Algeria",
    "AS": "American Samoa",
    "AD": "Andorra",
    "AO": "Angola",
    "AI": "Anguilla",
    "AQ": "Antarctica",
    "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AR": "Argentina",
    "AM": "Armenia",
    "AW": "Aruba",

};
```

i want to group by continent in an array using javascript then use conditional statement if selected country  is from europe {action} else if from asia{action}

```html
<select>
<option value="">Select Country</option>

<option value="['Afghanistan','AF']">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="['Åland Islands','AX']">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="['Albania','AL']">Albania</option>
<option value="['Algeria','DZ']">Algeria</option>
<option value="['American Samoa','AS']">American Samoa</option>
<option value="['Andorra','AD']">Andorra</option>
<option value="['Angola','AO']">Angola</option>
<option value="['Anguilla','AI']">Anguilla</option>
<option value="['Antarctica','AQ']">Antarctica</option>
<option value="['Antigua and Barbuda','AG']">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="['Argentina','AR']">Argentina</option>
<option value="['Armenia','AM']">Armenia</option>
<option value="['Aruba','AW']">Aruba</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you know the continent of each country code? Also, you seem to be having encoding problems regarding `Åland Islands`...

Comment: Who would vote this question up? There's no sign of any attempt at a solution, and it's not really clear what's even being asked.

Comment: @Pointy - I've noticed this of late. I suspect students supporting each other thru automatic upvoting.

Comment: *"in an array"*: where is the array? You provide HTML. That is not an array. Is your question about HTML or an array? What is the expected output?

Comment: You should use an Api which comes with country informations. Otherwise you have to create hardcoded objects and continent information to group each country and continent. Have a look at this Api https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Comment: You could also add `disabled selected` to the empty option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the element and extract the country code to check if it's in an array.
But you should get the country codes using an API.

```js
const EUROPE = ['AX'];
const ASIA = ['AF'];

function countrySelected(element) {
  let countrycode = element.value.split("'")[3];
  if (EUROPE.includes(countrycode, 0)) {
    console.log("Europe");
  } else if (ASIA.includes(countrycode, 0)) {
    console.log("Asia");
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="countrySelected(this);">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Country</option>
  <option value="['Afghanistan','AF']">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="['Åland Islands','AX']">Åland Islands</option>
</select>
```